# multiple parallel threads in java dont terminate

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, garbage-collection, hyperthreading

i try to run a set of parallel thread in java. im creating these through a high order function as follows:

```
public static void parallelizedMap(Consumer<String> f, List<String> list, int count) {
    List<List<String>> parts = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    int L = N / (count - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
        parts.add(new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L))));
    }
    for (List<String> e : parts) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                e.forEach(f);
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
}
```

this method is called every few minutes. it creates hundreds of thread after several minutes. every thread only runs for 20 seconds. but my debugging showed that they never terminate and therefor i get this Exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

thanks in advance

Comment: *every thread only runs for 20 seconds. but my debugging showed that they never terminate.* Those statements contradict each other. And we can't see what `f` is doing, so it's hard to offer much help.

Comment: Some advice: Use meaningful variable names! Also, provide a complete example.

Comment: if you use debugger, suspend any thread that must finish but didn't, and look at what statement it hangs.

Comment: hey thanks, f is checking a value in a database and the threads are waiting for some other thread to finish the database connection, i marked these methods synchronized. maybe this is leading to a deadlock situation, because there are threads that are created faster than they can connect to the database... is there a proper way to connect to mysql database without using synchronized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me the solution was to give every thread an extra jdbc connection and dont let them share one. this resolved the deadlock und they terminate as expected.

Comment: are you serious?

Comment: This question and answer really is of little help to anyone else.  You don't even mention JDBC in your question.  Considering editing for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the problem are the threads. But if count is double or more than size of list:

```
final int N = list.size(); // N = 10, count = 22
int L = N / (count - 1);  // L = 10 / (22-1) = 0.476 / L = 0.4d = (int) 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 0) {
     parts.add(new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + 0))));
}
```

The iteration is an endless-loop but the memory-usage grows every iteration.

Naturally its a OutOfMemory.

Comment: isnt it 10 / 4 = 2.5 => (int) 2 ?

Comment: ok, i see your point. this is correct, but in my case it will always be N >> count and this will not happen ;)